# would like to restrict oracle spatial shapes to simple polygons

Tags: oracle-spatial

I'm rather new to oracle spatial. I'd like to restrict shapes to simple polygons. multiple polygons are ok. donuts are not. crossed edges are not. and all shapes must be separated by a tolerance.

SDO_GEOM.VALIDATE_GEOMETRY_WITH_CONTEXT seems like a good place to start... but would appreciate any further insight on how to determine that I do not have donuts.

any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

found what I needed here:
https://spatialdbadvisor.com/oracle_spatial_tips_tricks/89/sdo_utilgetnumrings-an-alternative

with additional information from the documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_objrelschema.htm#SPATL020